# Smooth map from manifold to good orbifold

Tags: differential-topology

I have the following question: there seem to be several inequivalent definitions of smooth maps between orbifolds, as indicated in [Borzellino and Brunsden - The Stratified Structure of Spaces of Smooth Orbifold Mappings](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1070).

My question is: given the easiest situation, where $X$ is a smooth manifold and $Y=M/G$ with $M$ a smooth manifold and $G$ a finite group, do all these notions coincide? That is, is it 'unambiguous' what $C^\infty(X,Y)$ is in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Note that, since your username is automatically displayed below your question, it is not usual (and indeed [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)) to sign your post in the body.  I edited accordingly, while tidying up some other minor issues.